# Excel floating point precision "ROUND()" hack not working

Tags: excel, vba

In real life outside of binary systems, $50.00 / 13,084 / 1,000 = $3.821461

When formatted as currency, Excel renders it as $0.000003821461326811370000000000

Some of you have probably been in my shoes. However, my research shows that there are only two solutions to this issue.

**Solution 1/2:** Check "Set precision as displayed" as explained [here](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Set-rounding-precision-e5d707e3-07a8-4df2-810c-218c531eb06a), however that makes the data inaccurate over time and I would like to stay away from this solution.

**Solution 2/2:** Use the ROUND() function. Well, that's not working for me either:

=ROUND(50/13084/1000,6) renders as $0.000004

What is the issue here? Have I misidentified the real problem?

Comment: Your first line is wrong. What you mean is $50.00 / (13,084 / 1,000) = $3.821461 so you need the parentheses in Excel too. Or use $50.00 / 13,084 * 1,000 = $3.821461

Comment: Wow, THANK YOU! Why is it that I can enter that first line into a calculator and it calculates correctly? (Be sure to make an answer so I can select yours).

Comment: Your calculator should really not display 3.82 unless it is not correctly using order of operations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first line is wrong based on the established BODMAS (or other acronym!) principles.

What you mean is $50.00 / (13,084 / 1,000) = $3.821461 so you need the parentheses in Excel too. Or use $50.00 / 13,084 * 1,000 = $3.821461

See explanation here: https://www.mathsisfun.com/operation-order-bodmas.html